# Given a set of points $S$ which is a subset of a vector space $V$, find the smallest subspace which intersect $S$ in at least $k$ points

Tags: algorithms, linear-algebra

Given a set of points $S$ which is a subset of a vector space $V$ I want to want the smallest subspace of $A$ of $V$ such that $|A \cap S| \geq k $.

I suspect some variant of this problem would have already been studied but I have not been able to find it. Have anyone seen this or something similar before?

Answer (score 1):

In general, this problem is hard.  For instance, if we have a vector space over $GF(2)$, then checking whether there is a one-dimensional subspace $A$ with the desired property is as hard as [learning parity with noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_learning) (LPN).  LPN is conjectured to be hard: I believe there are subexponential-time algorithms, but as far as I know, there are no known polynomial-time algorithms.  The hardness will depend on the specific parameters, i.e., the dimension of $V$, the size of $S$, and the value of $k$.

Comment: Okei, that certainly seems very related. thanks